# Vim in OSX: How to do page-up/page-down/go to EOL through a vim file opened in terminal?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, shortcuts, macvim

In putty, which is how I primarily used VIM, I could do the following:

- Page up/down : Using the native Page up/down key. In Mac, the alternative is Fn + Up/Down, which doesn't work in the terminal (doesn't scroll inside the vim file, but scrolls the terminal buffer)
- Similarly, the Fn + right/left keys do not take me to start/end of line

How do I emulate this functionality in Mac OS X ?

Comment: It could help clarify your question if you replaced or augmented "Fn + right/left" with "Home/End", which is what those Fn combinations do.

Answer (score 72):

This isn't specifically a mac question, this is really a vi question.

In navigation mode, ctrl-f scrolls down a page and ctrl-b scrolls up a page (think "F"orward and "B"ack). Ctrl-d scrolls down half a page, and ctrl-u scrolls up half a page.

^ takes you to the beginning of a line, and $ to the end. I know, I know, but there are historical reasons for that.

[Here's](http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi2.html) a really good cheat-sheet on vi controls. vi is a little bit arcane, but once you internalize it, it's the quickest and slickest text editor in the world.

Comment: "This isn't specifically a mac question, this is really a vi question." It's mostly about how to set up the Mac OS X Terminal application's keymap, but it turns out that the second part of the question, about start/end of line, already has a mapping in Terminal and one possible solution is to edit vi's map to understand it. Alternatively, the Terminal keyboard map could be edited.

Comment: Here is another helpful website: https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html

Answer (score 17):

Terminal's default preferences map <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Page Down</kbd> to the character sequences that tell programs like Vim and Emacs to scroll (`ESC [ 5 ~` and `ESC [ 6 ~`).

If you want these keys to send character sequences to the terminal without the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier, you can customize the keyboard map:

> **Terminal > Preferences > Settings > [profile] > Keyboard**

If you do this, I recommend you invert the meaning of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier for these keys by swapping the mappings for the shifted and unshifted keys, so that the alternative behaviors are still available. Also, see the **View** menu, which contains scrolling commands that use the <kbd>Command</kbd> modifier so they're available regardless of the terminal keyboard map.

Similarly, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>End</kbd> are mapped to move to the start/end of the current line (`ESC [ H` and `ESC [ F`). These sequences are understood by Bash, but you may have to customize Vim to understand them, or edit the mappings specifically for Vim. Vim, Emacs, and some other programs send an escape sequence to put the terminal into “Application Cursor Mode”, where the Home/End keys send `ESC O H` and `ESC O F`, but Terminal (as of 10.9) does not implement this behavior. So you may wish to change the keyboard map to send these other codes instead (Bash also understands them). (On other OSes, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> are used for start/end of line, so Terminal provides them with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier for symmetry.)

<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> are also mapped to "move to start/end of line" sequences by default, though they're different from the ones mapped to <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>End</kbd>. Instead, they're mapped to the Emacs- and Bash-compatible sequences `ESC [ 5 D` and `ESC [ 5 C`. Assuming these aren't in use by Vim, the simplest approach would be to customize Vim to accept these, using ~/.vimrc.

Note that in more-recent versions of macOS, Terminal no longer has explicit mappings for <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> in the preferences by default. Instead, it has a dynamic behavior where the keys automatically map to start/end-of-line when the alternate screen is active—e.g., when using a full-screen application like emacs, vim, screen or tmux. When using a line-oriented program like a shell on the main screen, they continue to scroll the terminal view by default. The <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier inverts the behavior.

Comment: @MarkHu I covered that in the last paragraph.

Comment: As covered partially in the last paragraph, defaults may be different/missing in other versions of MacOS. For 10.13.6, I had to add `\033[5~` (and ...6.) for PageDown/Up.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest and best solution is `n`+`↓`, where `n` is the number of lines you would like to go down, and `↓` is the down key.

I regularly just do `12`+`↓` and `22`+`↓`.

Comment: your comment helps the job done! brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

I was used to Home/End getting me to the start and end of lines in Insert mode (from use in Windows and I think Linux), which Mac doesn't support.  This is particularly annoying because when I'm using vim on a remote system, I also can't easily do it.  After some painful trial and error, I came up with some `.vimrc` lines which do the same thing, and eventually found someone else who came up with a similar solution here:

https://coderwall.com/p/fd_bea

Enjoy.

```
:inoremap <C-e> <C-o>$
:inoremap <C-a> <C-o>0
```